# Optimise MySQL reading pattern

Tags: java, mysql, algorithm, jdbc

I have an Integer-collection with filtered row-IDs in which I am trying to search for sequences/ranges to optimise a MySQL select-query. To give you an example:

The Integer-Collection can be either very fragmented:

```
[1,2,88,101,200] = Sequence(1-2,88,101,200)
```

Or very entirely:

```
[1,2,3,4,..,198,199,200] = Sequence(1-200)
```

Is there any Java-algorithm to find a sequence in the collection or to improve my reading-pattern in general?

Comment: IMHO, you should be able to collect the ranges using a loop or two. I doubt there is any library function that would do just this.

Answer (score 1):

How long are your collections? Unless you have millions of items, it is probably fastest to load a collection entirely into memory, sort it and then scan for ranges.

In a sorted list, finding ranges is trivial. Just scan it sequentially; if the next element is not previous element + 1, one range has just ended, and another began.

Comment: The collection has in the "worst" case around 1'000'000 items, wherefrom in some cases only 40-50 items are needed.

Comment: And the problem is that these 40-50 items are probably not in a row what results in a lot of single MySQL-queries = low performance.